# Progruard and R8 being deprecated - Android Studio 3.6

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I'm getting deprecated warnings in regards to Proguard as well as R8 after upgrading my Android Studio to 3.6. Does that mean we shouldn't use obfuscation in our projects or is there another equivalent option we should consider while building in release mode?

> The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
>   It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.
>   Affected Modules: etc

Comment: Can you please share the messages that you are getting?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "deprecated warnings" in this context? The actual text of the warnings could help.

Comment: I don't remember exact message, but it said it's being deprecated. Side note: I've got it after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6

Comment: To get an answer you should post the _full, exact_ warning message. For example, the `useProGuard` setting has been deprecated a while ago - maybe that's what you saw and you're misremembering it.

Comment: I've been switching to R8 this week and removing all `useProGuard` from my gradle's

Comment: Ok, message copy-pasted

Comment: As the messages states, only ProGuard will be deprecated. Obfuscation will be there, using R8. The *switch* for the deprecated ProGuard is deprecated as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Does that mean we shouldn't use obfuscation in our projects

No. You can use obfuscation and optimization tooling.

> is there another equivalent option we should consider while building in release mode

If you have `android.enableR8 = true` in your `gradle.properties`, remove it as R8 it the default tooling and the `android.enableR8` setting itself is deprecated, causing these deprecation warnings.

If you have `android.enableR8 = false` to use proguard for optimiation and obfuscation, consider migrating to R8 instead.

Comment: how to make the project obfuscate? I removed all the given properties and said to remove the dependency of R8 from build.gradle and i can't compile the project anymore, i get R8NullPointerException what's that?

Comment: That looks like something beyond the scope of comment section here.

Comment: @laalto What I got from your answer is that R8 will work automatically so no need to add `android.enableR8 = true`, right?

Comment: @Mohamed That's my understanding too, provided that you have Android Gradle plugin 3.6 or newer.

Comment: That is promised proguard configuration should be 100% compatible with new R8. Unfortunately, R8 has completly destroyed my release build and it looks like most ProGuard rules were just ignored. As I have no time for any further analysing, I am stuck to use ProGuard, sad news in Gradle 7.0 it won't be possible to disable R8. So I don't think I am going to update my project to Gradle 7.0 when available

Comment: Is there a way where in build.gradle if we can specify any obfuscation tool that is used from our side and hence don't want R8 obfuscation on top of it?

Comment: @user1209216 are you sure enableR8 will not work in Gradle 7.0? Can you please share your source for this info?

Comment: No need to share anything, just read warning message - it says Gradle 5.0 will remove ability to disable R8: `WARNING: The option setting 'android.enableR8=false' is deprecated.
 It will be removed in version 5.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
 You will no longer be able to disable R8`